# Elementary proof for average number of tree components in a random forest of fixed size

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, combinatorial-proofs

In Flajolet's & Sedgewick's ["Analytic Combinatorics"](https://books.google.com/books?id=0h-4QcA1c1QC&pg=PA632&lpg=PA632&dq=degree%20distribution%20catalan%20tree%20binomial&source=bl&ots=fFLUx8C3fF&sig=mUQkdcH8iKC4zXCuSW5wtuqXnw8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) I found the statement that for a forest ("Catalan", i.e. collection of ordered trees) of size $n$, uniformly distributed, the number of tree components $X_n$ satisfies $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=k)=\frac{k}{2^{k+1}},$$
but the proof seems to use a lot of heavy(?) machinery introduced in the previous chapters to derive that. Is there also an elementary proof that might provide a little bit more insight?

Comment: What's a uniform distribution for a forest?

Comment: There are only finitely many, say $f(n)$, forests of size $n$; now pick any of those with equal probability $\frac{1}{f(n)}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let  me start  by  pointing out  that  a problem  that requires  heavy
machinery from  the canonical text  is unlikely to have  an elementary
proof.  Here is  what we  can  do. The  species of  Catalan trees  has
specification

$$\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{Z} \times \mathfrak{S}(\mathcal{H}).$$

This yields the functional equation 
$$z = H(z) (1-H(z)).$$

As we follow the text we see  that the forests in question are in fact
ordered    as    opposed    to    being   sets,    another    possible
interpretation. Therefore we  will adopt this in our  work. (One might
think forests are sets of trees  rather than sequences but this is not
asked for here.) We get for the species of forests

$$\mathcal{F} = \mathfrak{S}(\mathcal{U}\mathcal{H}).$$

with OGF

$$F(z, u) = \frac{1}{1 - u H(z)}.$$

We need to count these for the probabilities. We obtain

$$F(z, 1) = \frac{1}{1 - H(z)}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$[z^n] F(z, 1) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-H(z)} \; dz.$$

From the functional equation we put $z = w(1-w)$ so that $dz = 1-2w \;
dw$ to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1} (1-w)^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-w} (1-2w)\; dw.$$

This yields two pieces

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1} (1-w)^{n+1}} 
\; dw = {2n\choose n}$$

and

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n} (1-w)^{n+2}} 
\; dw = -{2n\choose n+1}$$

for a result of

$$\left(1-\frac{n}{n+1}\right) {2n\choose n}
= \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}.$$

These  are  the regular  Catalan  numbers and  what  we  have here  is
folklore. Continuing we have

$$[u^k] F(z, u) = H(z)^k.$$

Extracting coefficients yields the integral

$$[z^n] H(z)^k =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} H(z)^k \; dz.$$

The functional equation applies as before and we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1} (1-w)^{n+1}} w^k
 (1-2w)\; dw.$$

We once more have two pieces, getting

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1} (1-w)^{n}}
\; dw
= {2n-1-k\choose n-1}$$

and

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n-k} (1-w)^{n+1}}
\; dw
= - {2n-1-k\choose n}$$

for a result of

$$\left(\frac{n}{n-k} - 1\right) {2n-1-k\choose n}
= \frac{k}{n-k} {2n-1-k\choose n}.$$

Switching to probabilities we have the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{\frac{k}{n-k} {2n-1-k\choose n} \times 
(n+1) {2n\choose n}^{-1}.}$$

Using the [asymptotics for the central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) we get

$$\frac{k}{n-k} {2n-1-k\choose n} \times 
(n+1) \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}.$$

Continuing  as  documented in  part  eight,  page  $25$ (saddle  point
asymptotics) of  the slides for the  book we now  introduce $G(z)$ and
$f(z)$ matching  the notation used there with  $G(z) = (1+z)^{2n-1-k}$
and

$${2n-1-k\choose n} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{2n-1-k} \; dz$$

and with $f(z) = \log G(z) - (n+1) \log z = (2n-1-k) \log(1+z) - (n+1)
\log z$ (we apply the method to $\exp f(z)$). Solving the saddle point
equation

$$f'(z) = 0 = (2n-1-k)\frac{1}{1+z} - (n+1)\frac{1}{z}$$

we obtain for the saddle point

$$\zeta = \frac{n+1}{n-k-2} \sim 1.$$

The saddle point approximation of the binomial coefficient is thus

$${2n-1-k\choose n} \sim 
\frac{G(1)}{1^{n+1} \sqrt{2\pi f''(1)}}.$$

With $f''(z) = -(2n-1-k)\frac{1}{(1+z)^2} + (n+1)\frac{1}{z^2}$
we obtain

$$\frac{2^{2n-1-k}}{\sqrt{2\pi (n+1-(n/2-1/4-k/4))}}
\\ = \frac{2^{2n-1-k}}{\sqrt{2\pi (n/2+5/4+k/4)}}
= \frac{2^{2n-1-k}}{\sqrt{\pi (n+5/2+k/2)}}.$$

With $k$ fixed this is asymptotic to

$$\frac{2^{2n-1-k}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

Substitute into the probability to get

$$\frac{k}{n-k} \frac{2^{2n-1-k}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
(n+1) \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}
= k \frac{n+1}{n-k} \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}
\sim \frac{k}{2^{k+1}}$$

as  claimed.  For  it  to be  genuinely  elementary we  would need  an
elementary  proof  of  the  binomial  coefficient  asymptotics,  which
however is at least as difficult as Stirling's approximation.

**Addendum.** Observe  that we have introduced a  singularity at $n=k$
into the  closed form  probabilities during simplification,  which did
not affect the result, as $k$  is fixed while $n$ goes to infinity. An
alternate version is

$$\left(1-\frac{n-k}{n}\right) {2n-1-k\choose n-1}
= \frac{k}{n} {2n-1-k\choose n-1}.$$

We get for the probability

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{\frac{k}{n} {2n-1-k\choose n-1} \times 
(n+1) {2n\choose n}^{-1}.}$$

We can verify that these probabilities sum to one by computing

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2n-1-k\choose n-1}
- \sum_{k=0}^n {2n-1-k\choose n}.$$

Using the almost  the same integral as during  the saddle point method
we get for the first sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n}} (1+z)^{2n-1}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(1+z)^k} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n}} (1+z)^{2n-1}
\frac{1-1/(1+z)^{n+1}}{1-1/(1+z)} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{2n-1}
(1+z-1/(1+z)^{n}) \; dz
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{2n} - [z^n] (1+z)^{n-1}
= {2n\choose n}.$$

The second sum yields

$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+2}} (1+z)^{2n-1}
(1+z-1/(1+z)^{n}) \; dz
\\ = - ([z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{2n} - [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{n-1})
= -{2n\choose n+1}.$$

We get

$$\left(1-\frac{n}{n+1}\right) {2n\choose n}
= \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}$$

and we may  conclude that the probabilities do indeed  sum to one. The
evaluation  of  binomial coefficient  sums  using  the Cauchy  Residue
Theorem is known as the Egorychev method.

Comment: Very nice and instructive presentation. (+1)

Comment: Any chance you could add a link to "the slides of the book"? (assuming you're not referring to a particular part of it)

Comment: Google finds the slides at this [AC link](http://ac.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/).